# Breakpoints using SkelJS - Adjustments for widescreen monitor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm working with a responsive site with a SkelJS framework.  Overall, I'm happy with the site, but I'm having an issue widening a jquery slideshow on the home page for wide monitors.  It looks fine on mobile, tablet and my laptop screen, but when I push it over to my large monitor, I don't like the space between the left and right of the slide show and the edge of the screen.

The config.js file is setup as follows:

```
window._skel_config = {
prefix: 'css/style',
resetCSS: true,
boxModel: 'border',
grid: {
    gutters: 50
},
breakpoints: {
    'mobile': {
        range: '-480',
        lockViewport: true,
        containers: 'fluid',
        grid: {
            collapse: true,
            gutters: 10
        }
    },
    'desktop': {
        range: '481-',
        containers: 1200
    },
    '1000px': {
        range: '481-1200',
        containers: 960
    }
}
```

};

I'm learning the js side as I go, so if anyone wanted to give me a layman's response, I'd be sincerely grateful.

I'm trying to understand why the "desktop" breakpoint would range from '481-*_*' and have a container size of 1200 and the "1000px" breakpoint would go from '481-1200' with a 960 container.

I've played around with adjusting the '1000px' parameters to include larger sizes (up to 1900) and adjusting the container size, but it destroys all of my CSS formatting.

The site in question is www.rmcabinetry.com.

Thanks in advance for any help!!!  This community has been an awesome resource.  I'm trying not to abuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Per their docs,
"Note: Since breakpoint ranges are allowed to overlap, more than one can be active at any given time. When this happens, the options of each are combined in order with those defined last taking precedence."

This would suggest the containers will equal 1200 if the screen width is 481 and above but not when it is lower than 1200.

In the template you are using from HTML5UP, the slideshow is wrapped in a parentDiv which has a banner background image that is scaling to avoid the gaps on the left and right.

Comment: That makes sense.  So if the breakpoint ranges are overlapping, on say a 1000px screen, how do I then identify which options are "defined last".  Is it referring to the js options (containers, gutters, etc) or to the CSS options.

For example, let's say the CSS tied to resizing a logo on the "desktop" CSS was 30% auto and the "1000px" CSS had 40% auto, which CSS would take precedent?

Answer (score 0):

Your settings look a little muddled.  Try adjusting them so that your defaults come first (i.e. are loaded first, which is why "range: '*'," is first below) and are followed by breakpoints breaking down the range that will then override them (via order of precedence).  Also, state ranges as shown below, with the - before the number (I think this will solve your problem).  I would also  vary your gutters and change them across ranges for better effects.  Try these:

```
{
prefix: 'css/style',
resetCSS: true,
boxModel: 'border',
containers: 1200,
useOrientation: true,
breakpoints: {
  'widest': { range: '*', containers: 1360, grid: { gutters: 50 }, hasStyleSheet: false },
  'wide': { range: '-1680', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
  'normal': { range: '-1280', containers: 960, grid: { gutters: 30 }, lockViewport: true },
  'narrow': { range: '-1000', containers: '100%', grid: { gutters: 25, collapse: true }, lockViewport: true },
  'mobile': { range: '-640', containers: '100%', grid: { gutters: 10, collapse: true }, lockViewport: true }
}
```

You then need to make a css page for each of these breakpoints (except 'widest', as stated above) to adjust their individual styles (i.e. 'css/style-wide.css', 'css/style-normal.css', 'css/style-narrow.css', 'css/style-mobile.css').  The prefix setting will find them so long as you link them via 'css/style' as the beginning part of your link href.  Adjusting styles in these sheets will only affect the style at the size you desire, giving you the freedom to make the adjustments you seek.